# We are two immediate neighbors who forged our own powers to form concatenated relationship. Who are we?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers, number-theory

Our concatenated number is $ \overline{ABAC}, $ where $ A, B, C $ are all positive digits (1 - 9).

Our relationship is

$$ \overline{ABAC} = A^A + B^B + A^A + C^C $$

Who are we?

Comment: Having read [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185319/is-it-a-munchausen-number) which appeared in the HNQ just today made this puzzle very easy ;-)

Comment: @Christoph.  What is HNQ?

Comment: [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), a selection of questions from the whole Stack Exchange network which are "featured" to appear in the right-hand sidebar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the solution

> $A=3, B=4, C=5$ 
>  $3^3 + 4^4 + 3^3 + 5^5 = 3435$

Reasoning

> $2 \times 4^4 = 512$ and $6^6=46656$ which is more than four digits so at least one of the digits has to be $5$ and the others have to be less than or equal to $5$. 
>  Then, we have $5^5=3125$ and since double this is more than $6000$, the digit $5$ can appear only once. Furthermore, since $3125 + 2 \times 4^4 < 4000$, the digit $3$ must also appear at least once. 
>  Since $5^5 + 3^3 = 3152$, the other unique digit to appear must either be $1$ or $4$ (as this will necessarily be the $2$nd digit). This leaves a small number of possibilities to try.

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it. I think I got a *slightly* slicker solution by deducing some extra conditions required on $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 21):

### Initial bounds

- > $6^6$ is too big as it has 5 digits.
- > $4^4$ is only 256, too small if everything was at most that.

So at least one of $A,B,C$ must be

> $5$.

### Narrowing possibilities

- > $B$ must be even, because $ABAC$ and $C^C$ have matching parity. So $B=2$ or $B=4$.
- > If $A=5$, then $A^A+A^A$ is already bigger than $6000$, too big. But $5^5=3125$ is involved somewhere, so $A$ must be at least $3$. So $A=3$ or $A=4$.

So the only option

> to be $5$ is $C$.

### Final answer

- > Trying $A=4$ gives $4B45=3637+B^B$, which is impossible since $2^2$ and $4^4$ are too small to get that high.
- > Trying $A=3$ gives $3B35=3179+B^B$, which works with $B=4$.

So the final answer is

> $A=3,B=4,C=5$.